Definition of Realized Gamma
What is the formal definition of "realized gamma" and how would one go about calculating it?
$$ \Gamma_{R} := \int_{t}^{T} \frac{1}{2} S^2 \gamma dt $$
The question is different than delta-hedging altough from the same application area in that it goes deeper into the aspect of "realized gamma" and how it is defined. Also do not confuse realized vol with realized gamma - both multiplied give the portfolio variance.
Also note we don't make any assumptions about expectation under Q (ref implied volatility) or P-measures (ref market volatility), and as such this is valid under any assumption (not only Black-Scholes but any other model like Bachelier, etc..).
My starting point is based on this article that I found here. No relation whatsoever with the author - it's just one of the few google hits I got.
So we start with the definition of gamma dollars:
$$ \Gamma_{DV}:=\frac{1}{2} S^2 \gamma$$
The variational principle tells us that the price of an option changes by dV when the spot changes by dS:
$$ dV = \delta \cdot dS+\frac{1}{2}\gamma\cdot dS^2+...$$
with
$$ \delta:= \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} $$
$$ \gamma := \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} $$
We are interested in the second term only which picks up the sigma.
$$ dS:=\mu S dt + \sigma S dW $$
$$ dS^2 = \sigma^2 S^2 dt$$
Replacing back, and discretizing, we have the change in value of the option due to the second term only:
$$ dV = ... + \Gamma_{DV} \sigma^2 dt + ...$$
As far as I can tell then the definition of "realized gamma" is then:
$$ \Gamma_{R} := \int_{t}^{T} \Gamma_{DV} dt = \int_{t}^{T} \frac{1}{2} S^2 \gamma dt$$
with the implied fact that the portfolio change due to that is:
$$ \Delta V = \Gamma_{R} \cdot (\sigma^2_1 - \sigma^2_0) $$
Is this correct?
